# How to position absolute element in a container?

Tags: html, css, navigation, position

I am trying to make a menu with sub-menu under an element by giving the main menu's `il` relative position and the `ul` inside it absolute position. Why does the sub-menu treats the to `ul` as it's container and not it's parent `li`?

the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

the CSS:

```
nav a {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #C0C0C0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

nav li {
    position: relative;
}

nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/6pgHa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because it is your anchor tags that are floated left and therefore defining the position, not the li elements.

Change the `nav a` selector to `nav li` and this fixes it. The li elements don't really have a position in your current code.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle to make the menu work the way I guess you want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/6pgHa/3/

```
nav {
 width: 600px;
 margin: 50px auto 0;
}

nav > ul li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

nav > ul li a {
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 border: solid 1px #C0C0C0;
 display:inline-block;
}


nav > ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 top:50px;
 left:-9999px;
}

nav > ul li:hover ul {
 left:0;
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity: why is it when I use the `left:-9999px;` the length of each inner `a` is according to its' content but when I remove it, the are all sized according to their parent `li`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. All that left:-9999px is doing is moving the UL way off to the left by 9999px so you can't see it. Then when you hover it changes the 'left' property to be '0' which brings it back to where it originaly started.

Comment: I know. look at the width of the sub-menu items when you use the hiding technique, and then simply remove `left:-9999px;` and look at their widths again.